# Argument of type string is not assignable to paramMap

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I tried to create some basic function in the ionic framework.

I have declared ID as a number in model.ts and created a function to access that value using paramMap it shows an error that string is not assignable to a number.

I am using Ionic 4.0.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('placeId')) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/places/tabs/discover');
        return;
      }
       this.place = this.placesService.getplace(paramMap.get('placeId'));
    });
  }
```

`service.ts` is where I wrote the `getplace` function:

```
getplace(id: number) {
    return {...this._places.find(
      p => p.id === id
    )};
  }
```

Model:

```
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
export class place {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public user_id: number,
        public title: string,
        public cooked_time: Date,
        public dispose_time: Date,
        public food_type: string,
        public description: string,
        public serve_quantity: number,
        public imageUrl: string,
        public lat: number,
        public long: number
    ) {}
}
```

I am expecting to pass a number and that function is taking it as a string.

Comment: can't you cast via <number>

Comment: @jcuypers bro I am totally new to it can you just gimme a dummy example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "+" in your call to

```
this.placesService.getplace(+paramMap.get('placeId'))
```

to covert string to number

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('placeId')) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/places/tabs/discover');
        return;
      }
       this.place = this.placesService.getplace(+paramMap.get('placeId'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: I searched frantically for an answer why I kept getting a number when I wanted a string, and this "+" was the problem. Thanks, Thivanka!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this "bro" :)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('placeId')) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/places/tabs/discover');
        return;
      }
       this.place = this.placesService.getplace(<number>paramMap.get('placeId'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: while adding <number> tag just i have to add <unkown> tag and it takes number